# Opposite of numpy.reduce

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

So in `numpy` we have a `reduce` function with which we can reduce one dimension of an array by applying a function to the elements across that dimension. Is there also an inverse of this function that would take a single element and expand it to a whole new dimension?

Let's say I have these two arrays:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.value = a, b, c

a = np.array([A(1,2,3), A(4,5,6)])
b = np.array([1<<8 | 2<<4 | 3, 4<<8 | 5<<4 | 6])
```

And I would like to transform either of these two arrays into

```
np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

What I'm currently doing is the following:

```
def expand(arr):
    a = np.empty((*arr.shape, 3))
    for x, y in np.ndindex(arr.shape):
        if isinstance(arr[x,y], A):
            a[x,y] = arr[x,y].value
        else:
            a[x,y] = arr[x,y] >> 8, arr[x,y] >> 4 & 0xF, arr[x,y] & 0xF
    return a
```

This works, but I'd like to avoid (slow?) iteration since it goes against the spirit of `numpy`.

I've also tried a solution using `np.vectorize`, but it doesn't work as I'd want it to:

```
def expanded(element):
    if isinstance(element, A):
        return element.value
    return element >> 8, element >> 4 & 0xF, element & 0xF
f = np.vectorize(expanded)
f(a)  # Prints a tuple of arrays instead of the desired single array
```

Is there a better way to expand a single value to a new dimension, either via some mathematical operation or via object attribute access?

Comment: [Numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [np.broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html#numpy.broadcast) is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Using objects in a numpy array already goes "*against the spirit ot `numpy`*" ;)

Comment: Also, your code is not reproducible

Comment: `expanded` returns a tuple, so its `vectorized` version does the same.  `vectorize` has a speed disclaimer.  The `b` expression isn't obvious.

Comment: Doing stuff on an array of objects requires iterating on those objects.

Comment: @SurajShourie I've checked `np.broadcast` before, but I'm not sure how to use it to expand to different values as described.

Comment: @mozway Somewhat agreed, but I need to have the elements saved as objects, so it's either a `numpy` array of objects or a list of objects, and since I already receive the encoded version (`b`) as a `numpy` array I used `numpy` arrays for this as well. For processing I transform them to proper `numpy` arrays, which is what I'm trying to do in the question.

Comment: @mozway I don't see why, other than forgetting to `import numpy as np`, the code should work and give the results described in the question.

Comment: @hpaulj yep, I found out from a linked question that `vectorize` doesn't actually do anything magical in the background regarding speed. As far as `b` goes, it's just a way to encode several (small) numbers into one (big) one. If you're familiar with C, this is often how flags are handled in the language. As for why, for example, `scipy`' only allows 2D sparse arrays, so if I want to save an image in `scipy`'s sparse format, I need to first encode the colours from 3-4 `uint8` numbers into a single `uint32` one.

Comment: @hpaulj fair enough, I'll stick with the iteration solution then.

Comment: Your `a` is object dtype.  If the objects implement methods like addition, then functions like `np.sum(a)` or `a+1` will work, though at a list comprehension speed.  Otherwise math on such an array is hit-or-miss.  `numpy` does not treat the values of such elements as a nother `dimension`.  Your `a` is 1d.  Sometimes `vectorize` (or `frompyfunc`) can 'streamline` operating on such an array - that is make the code simpler, but not faster.  Have you tried an "expand" function that converts the a,b,c values into one number?  `vectorize` of that would produce one array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array of `A` instances.

```
In [56]: a
Out[56]: 
array([<__main__.A object at 0x000001BE0C814220>,
       <__main__.A object at 0x000001BE138B8610>], dtype=object)
```

Define a `__repr__` to get a prettier display.

Iterate on the instances, returning the `value`:

```
In [59]: [np.array(i.value) for i in a]
Out[59]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

Which can be turned into one array with:

```
In [60]: np.vstack(_)
Out[60]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

or

```
In [61]: np.array(__)
Out[61]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

`vectorize` makes an array for each value returned for the instance, here 3 arrays:

```
In [62]: np.vectorize(lambda i: i.value)(a)
Out[62]: (array([1, 4]), array([2, 5]), array([3, 6]))
```

which can be turned to a transpose of the previous array:

```
In [63]: np.array(_)
Out[63]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Returning an array (instead of tuple), and specifying otypes, gives another object dtype array:

```
In [64]: np.vectorize(lambda i: np.array(i.value), otypes=[object])(a)
Out[64]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
In [65]: np.vstack(_)
Out[65]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

`signature` can produce the numeric array directly.  I don't think this is any faster.

```
In [66]: np.vectorize(lambda i: np.array(i.value), signature='()->(n)')(a)
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

A slightly more primative version of `vectorize` returns an object dtype array directly:

```
In [68]: np.frompyfunc(lambda i: np.array(i.value), 1,1)(a)
Out[68]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Comparative timings on this small example wont tell us much.  You need to explore a more realistic size `a`.

The fast `numpy` code works with numeric dtypes.  For object dtype speeds are all approximately equivalent to list comprehensions.